# @ManyToMany mapping in JPA throws Exception [EclipseLink-6076]

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have developed simple JPA2.1 application with Oracle 11g database using Eclipse 2.5.2. Following is my scenario - there are two entities with **@ManyToMany** relation

- Club
- People

**Club.java**

```java
@Entity(name = "CLUB")
public class Club {
    @Id
    private int c_id;
    private String c_name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, 
                fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CLUB_PEOPLE", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="c_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="p_id")) 
    private Set<People> people=new HashSet<People>();

    public int getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }
    public void setC_id(int c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }
    public String getC_name() {
        return c_name;
    }
    public void setC_name(String c_name) {
        this.c_name = c_name;
    }
    public Set<People> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    public void setPeople(Set<People> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }
    public void addPeople(People p){
        getPeople().add(p);
    }
}
```

**People.Java**

```java
@Entity(name="people")
public class People{
    @Id     
    private int p_id;   
    private String name ;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="people")
    private Set<Club> club;

    public int getP_id() {
        return p_id;
    }
    public void setP_id(int p_id) {
        this.p_id = p_id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```java
public class Client1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = 
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPA-Query");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Club> cq = cb.createQuery(Club.class).distinct(true);
        Root<Club> root = cq.from(Club.class);

        final List<Predicate> requiredCriteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        final Join people = root.join("people", JoinType.LEFT);

        requiredCriteria.add(cb.or(cb.isNull(people)));
        requiredCriteria.add(cb.isNull(people.get("name")));
        requiredCriteria.add(cb.equal(people.get("name"), "people1"));

        TypedQuery<Club> q = em.createQuery(
            cq.where(cb.or(requiredCriteria
                .toArray(new Predicate[requiredCriteria.size()])
            ))
        );

        List<Club> allemps = q.getResultList();
        em.close();          
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Tables -

```sql
CREATE TABLE Club(
    c_id number NOT NULL,
    c_name VARCHAR2(20)
) 
ALTER TABLE Club ADD CONSTRAINT CLUGGRPPK PRIMARY KEY (c_id);

CREATE TABLE People(
    p_id number NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR2(20) 
) 
ALTER TABLE People ADD CONSTRAINT PEOPLEGRPPK PRIMARY KEY (p_id);

CREATE TABLE CLUB_PEOPLE
( 
    C_ID number,
    P_ID number,
    CONSTRAINT CLUB_PEOPLEPK PRIMARY KEY (C_ID, P_ID),
    CONSTRAINT GROUP_FK FOREIGN KEY("C_ID") 
        REFERENCES "CLUB"("C_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PEOPLE_FK FOREIGN KEY("P_ID") 
        REFERENCES "PEOPLE"("P_ID") ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

When I run my Client.java it throws following exception

```
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping[people]]
Expression: [
Query Key people
   Base ManyToMany.Club]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Club )
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping[people]] 
Expression: [
Query Key people
   Base ManyToMany.Club]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Club )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:480)
    at ManyToMany.Client.main(Client.java:75)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6076] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 
Mapping: [org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping[people]] 
Expression: [
Query Key people
   Base ManyToMany.Club]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Club )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.unsupportedMappingForObjectComparison(QueryException.java:1170)
```

**Please help me to solve above issue. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: I think the issue is because of requiredCriteria.add(cb.or(cb.isNull(people))); cb.isNull causing the issue. How to solve this??

Comment: You should explain what you want the query to do. An or clause with a single element doesn't make sense. And a people name cannot be null and equal to "people1" at the same time. You're also using raw types instead of generics, and don't use the generated metamodel, so why don't you simply use a simple, readable JPQL query instead of criteria? Not respecting the Java naming conventions is also a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks JB. I am working on some application where I am facing above issue with cb.isNull(SetJoin<Z,E>) statement. I tried here to replicate the issue with demo example. It am newbie to JPA and it would be great if you could help me.

Comment: My issue goes when cb.isNull(people) is replaced with cb.isEmpty(people) and changing root.join(Club_.p_Name,JoinType.LEFT); to root.join("people",JoinType.LEFT);  I want understand why it comes with cb.isNull(people) and works with[ cb.isEmpty(people) and root.join("people",JoinType.LEFT) ].